# I'm starting with sails.js, I would like to know how do to capture data from a form and send it to a controller and then to a model

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I'm starting with sails, I would like to know how do to capture data from a form and send it to a controller and then to a model.

Answer (score 0):

first of all in your sails command line create a new api:`sails generate api user`
this will create for you a new api that you can visit in /user.it will also create a controller in the /api/controllers/UserController.js
and a model in /api/models/User.js

in your views folder create a user directory and inside create an index.js file. (views/User/index.js)

inside index js you can put a form like this:

```
<form action="http://your.domain.com/user/create" method="post">
    <!-- your form data... -->
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

after you have submitted your data go check /user to view all of user data.
after that go read the some of sails documentation to understand what you just did.

Answer (score 0):

I think what your looking for is the flow of data through the application code.  I'll do my best to explain it here.

1. I generally bind angular models to my forms so I can access them in an angular script.
2. Take this data and package it up on say a submit button and do a Ajax post, use Restangular to send it, or $http (it all depends on your preference)

   ```
           $http.post('/'+name+'/create', sendData).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
           success(data);
       }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
           error(data);
       });
   ```

This can be any kind of ajax post though.

Answer (score 0):

In this example, i used Bootstrap:

```
<form method="POST" action="/news" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="subject">Title</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subject" placeholder="Title">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="message">Message</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" name="message"></textarea>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Send</button>
</form>
```

You just have to set the property "name" = "model's attribute name" to each input and that would do the work for you!

In my config/routes i set 'POST /news': 'NewsController.create' and it worked.

I hope it helps!